# How to QoS on LAN with simultaneous streaming video and transferring files?

Tags: networking, lan, qos

My modem/router is NetComm Wireless NF12. PC 1 is a HTPC running Windows 8.1 and is connected to the modem/router via CAT6 ethernnet. PC 2 is running Windows 7 and is connected to the modem/router via 2 x TL-PA211 EOP adaptors (www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA211).  Both PCs are on the same network.

Often someone is using PC 2 and will play a video from PC 1. If however, at the same time there is a file being transferred from PC 2 to PC 1 then the video being played with stop/stutter and jump around.

What settings can I look at to make the video file play correctly? It looks like the QoS settings only impacts WAN traffic.

Comment: Are the two PCs on the same network?

Comment: Yes, both are on the same network.

Comment: Since they are both on the same network, then the traffic doesn't go through the router. Routers route between networks, not from a network to the same network. The traffic is passing through a bridge (layer-2), not a router (layer-3). There are business class switches (bridges) which can do a little bit of QoS, but it is pretty minimal. Real QoS happens on router queues.

Comment: Ron is right. Hard-wired connections have data passing through a layer-2 switch, not